# I can manully ssh2 to remote host, but paramiko can not, why?

Tags: python, linux, authentication, ssh, paramiko

I want use paramiko to ssh2 to a remote host by public-key authentication, I setup the keys like these steps:

On local:

```
    Local> ssh-keygen
    Generating 1024-bit dsa key pair
    9 o.oOo..oOo.o
    Key generated.
    Passphrase :
    Again :
    Private key saved to /home/local/.ssh2/id_dsa_1024_a
    Public key saved to /home/local/.ssh2/id_dsa_1024_a.pub

    Local> cd ~/.ssh2
    Local> echo "IdKey id_dsa_1024_a" > identification
    Local> scp id_dsa_1024.pub remote@remote-host:~/.ssh2/local.pub
```

On remote:

```
    Remote> ssh-keygen
    ...omit...
    Remote> cd ~/.ssh2
    Remote> echo "Key local.pub" > authorization
```

After things above, I can just use `ssh remote@remote-host` to login.

However,I failed to use python's paramiko module to login remote-host:

```
    conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
    conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    conn.connect(remote-host, 22, username=remote,password='')
```

Alway error: Authentication failed.

I'm so confused. :(

Comment: Have you tried passing `None` instead of the empty string as `password` parameter? What is the passphrase of the private key? Does it work if your key resides in `~/.ssh` instead of `~/.ssh2`?

Comment: Does it work if you add your key to an SSH agent?

Comment: @user946850 use '' instead of None is OK, before I used this code to login to other host by SSH, but this time is SSH2 not SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `key_filename` option when connecting? I'm not sure that paramiko will automatically look at your private key in `~/.ssh` like the SSH CLI client does.

[paramiko documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.17/api/client.html)

Comment: From the docs you linked to: "Authentication is attempted in the following order of priority: ... Any "id_rsa" or "id_dsa" key discoverable in ~/.ssh/"

Comment: Your private key is named `id_dsa_1024_a` in the question. Maybe that's why it's not being found?

Comment: Thanks @scompt.com, I make it like this:conn.connect(remote-host, 22, username=remote,password='',key_filename='/home/local/.ssh2/id_dsa_1024_a'), But not work.

Comment: Try not passing the `password` argument.

Comment: @scompt.com without `password`, error is: `not a valid DSA private key file`, but I'm pretty sure that 'id_dsa_1024_a' is a DSA key generated by ssh-keygen

Comment: Solution for me was to use `private_key_pass` argument

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.abspath('.ssh/known_hosts'))
ssh.connect(some_host_in_known_hosts)
```

this fixed the same issue for me quite well this morning using python 2.7